# Erro em trigger SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou tentando criar essa `trigger` no `SQLite`, mas não sei se é possível.

Tenho uma tabea `Remedios` e uma `Manutenção`. Quero que, quando tiver uma inserção na tabela `Manutenção`, ele faça um update dependendo da condição no `Case`, mas está dando erro no `Update`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGmovimentacao 
    AFTER INSERT 
    ON manutencao
    for each row 
        BEGIN
            Select Case
                When ( NEW.tpMov = 'S' )
                 then UPDATE Remedio set Remedio.RemedioDose = Remedio.RemedioDose - NEW.qtdDose where Remedio.idRemedio = NEW.idManutencao
            END;
        END;
```

Comment: Qual o erro?...

Comment: então, no SQLite Studio ele tarja de sublinhado vermelho do Update pra frente.

Comment: no Android Studio, tbm diz que o erro esta próximo ao Update

Comment: Então é erro de sintaxe. Você não pode executar uma instrução depois do `Then`, apenas retornar valores. Olha [aqui](http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg09.htm) por exemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teu trigger apresenta alguns erros de sintaxe. Aqui fica uma alternativa

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGmovimentacao AFTER INSERT ON manutencao
  WHEN NEW.tpMov = 'S'
  BEGIN
     UPDATE Remedio 
        SET Remedio.RemedioDose = Remedio.RemedioDose - NEW.qtdDose 
      WHERE Remedio.idRemedio = NEW.idManutencao
  END;
```

A instrução `FOR EACH ROW` é facultativa já que o SQLite apenas suporta  `FOR EACH ROW` triggers e não `FOR EACH STATEMENT` triggers.

Edit: Esta versão deverá actualizar o valor de RemedioDose de acordo com o tpMov.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGmovimentacao AFTER INSERT ON manutencao
  BEGIN
     UPDATE Remedio 
        SET Remedio.RemedioDose = Remedio.RemedioDose + 
                CASE 
                   WHEN NEW.tpMov = 'S' THEN NEW.qtdDose * (-1) 
                   WHEN NEW.tpMov = 'E' THEN NEW.qtdDose 
                   ELSE 
                END
      WHERE Remedio.idRemedio = NEW.idManutencao
  END;
```

Comment: ok. Fiz dessa forma, porem devo criar outro identico com o NEW.tpMov = 'E'   e somar a dose ??? isso ?

Comment: Não deve ser necessário criar outro trigger. new.tpMov = 'E' significa entrada?

Comment: Sim, E = Entrada e S = Saida

Comment: A segunda versão do trigger actualiza o valor da dose de acordo com o tipo de movimento.

Comment: vlw. vou testar